# is there a kafka avro console consumer for use with hortonworks schema registry in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, hortonworks-sam

I'm using kafka streams together with hortonworks schema registry for serialization/deserialization of data which works ok, but i have a problem trying to view avro records in a topic without having to write code. currently i have to loop through the data using `stream.foreach((key, value) -> System.out.println("Key = " + key + " Value = " + value));` to get a snippet of the data. any hints on a better way.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a kafka avro console consumer

That is only part of Confluent Platform.

You can use the `consumer.properties` file in the regular console consumer to set and configure the key/value deserializer, though, which is all that `kafka-avro-console-consumer` really does.